# Object.create not supported in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, internet-explorer-8

I came across an issue with a plugin that uses object.create in jquery to create a date dropdown.  I just noticed in IE 8 that it is throwing an error of:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'create'
```

Here is the code:

```
var dropdateobj = Object.create(dropdatefuncs);
dropdateobj.create(options, this);
$.data(this, 'dropdate', dropdateobj);
```

What is a good work around for IE8 or more cross browser compatible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not hard to find a shim if you look.

Comment: This is the first question that comes up in Google when searching for `Object.create IE8`. +1

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you need `Object.create`, there are good chances you may need to rely on other es5 features as well. Therefore, in most cases the appropriate solution would be to use [**es5-shim**](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).

However, if `Object.create` is the only thing you need and you only use it to purely setup the prototype chain, here's a lightweight poly-fill that doesn't support `null` as the first argument and doesn't support the second `properties` argument.

Here's the spec:

> 15.2.3.5 Object.create ( O [, Properties] )
>
> The create function creates a new object with a specified prototype.
>   When the create function is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> If Type(O) is not Object or Null throw a TypeError exception.
>
> Let obj be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression
>   new Object() where Object is the standard built-in constructor with
>   that name
>
> Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to O.
>
> If the argument Properties is present and not undefined, add own
>   properties to obj as if by calling the standard built-in function
>   Object.defineProperties with arguments obj and Properties.
>
> Return obj.

Here's the lightweight implementation:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(o, properties) {
        if (typeof o !== 'object' && typeof o !== 'function') throw new TypeError('Object prototype may only be an Object: ' + o);
        else if (o === null) throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support 'null' as the first argument.");

        if (typeof properties != 'undefined') throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support a second argument.");

        function F() {}

        F.prototype = o;

        return new F();
    };
}
```

Comment: The second parameter is a joke, I wonder if someone actually uses that ridiculously verbose syntax to create objects in actual code

Comment: @plalx: MDN is collaboratively-edited. There is no "official" one. I've seen some *seriously* flawed code on MDN. (Check out the first "compatibility" example on the [`Array#forEach` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), for instance. Completely and utterly wrong.) See the implementation in [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/) for something that at least makes a best effort where it can.

Comment: @Esailija: That ridiculously verbose syntax is currently the only syntax available for defining property descriptors.

Comment: @CrazyTrain defineProperty or defineProperties?

Comment: @Esailija: those use the same syntax for property descriptors.

Comment: @CrazyTrain yes but when I use those I have very special situation where I actually need to alter descriptors. Not every-day normal object creating which Object.create second parameter attempts to be.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this answer? It's *clearly* useful.

Comment: @Esailija: Sure, but when you need it, you need it. The second argument to `Object.create` isn't required. I wouldn't see a benefit in passing a single argument to `Object.create` then subsequently invoking `Object.defineProperties`

Comment: @CrazyTrain If you put it that way - a very minor convenience - then I agree. So far I have never needed this convenience though because I use object.create just to link prototype chains. My original comment was about every-day object creating using object.create - nobody uses the second argument in that case but they use a initializer function. And so far I only know that Raynos does this. lol

Comment: @Esailija: Well I do agree that the syntax is ridiculously verbose. AFAIK, that'll be remedied in ES6 with a literal syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Well if the community have not changed the implementation, it's because it is widely accepted and works well in most cases, since people mostly use `Object.create` to setup the prototype chain only. I am not saying there aren't better implementations and this one should be used in all cases however.

Comment: Ugh, don't use this! Stop using this crappy polyfill.

Comment: @naomik Then what would you suggest doing? (Please don't say "Upgrade your browser.")

Comment: @naomik That polyfill is perfectly fine in most cases. Anyway, `Object.create` can't be shimmed perfectly so trying to use it for more advanced use cases than simply setting up the prototype chain is just asking for trouble...

Answer (score 20):

There are several shims that provide this, including [this one](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/).

Note that [`Object.create`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) **can't** be perfectly shimmed, though, because amongst other things it can create non-enumerable properties or properties with getters and setters, which you can't do on all pre-ES5 browsers. (You can do getters and setters on some pre-ES5 browsers using proprietary syntax, but not on IE8 I don't believe.) It can only be pseudo-shimmed.

But a pseudo-shim will do for the use-case you've quoted.

Just for completeness, here's a simple version of the part that can be shimmed:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw "The multiple-argument version of Object.create is not provided by this browser and cannot be shimmed.";
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;
        return new ctor();
    };
}
```

Comment: This polyfill is much easier to read than the one proposed by plalx in the other answer although both do the trick.

Comment: @plalx: Re efficiency: I bet you it's unmeasurable :-) -- and certainly not material in any real-world use case. I prefer the cleanliness of absolutely no link between the created objects. *"Also, directly throwing strings in my opinion is not very good as it breaks the error contract."* There is no error contract in JavaScript. But yea, `new Error` might be better on browsers that support it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think you are right about not leaving a link. I changed the posted implementation to behave closer to the spec while remaining as lightweight as possible. Also converted to a community wiki.

Comment: @plalx: It's really great you curate the accepted answer so well, nice one. What SO's all about.

Answer (score 0):

#### This will make Object.create() work in IE 8.

I tried the shim/sham but that didn't work for me.

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
 Object.create = function(o, props) {
  function F() {}
  F.prototype = o;

  if (typeof(props) === "object") {
   for (prop in props) {
    if (props.hasOwnProperty((prop))) {
     F[prop] = props[prop];
    }
   }
  }
  return new F();
 };
}
```